# GitHub stopped counting my commits on one project

Tags: git, github

I mostly work on one large project full time but have a few side projects. I just noticed that GitHub has stopped counting my commits for my large project since February, in my profile as well as in the project. That project is set to private, however, my contribution settings are set to show both public and private projects. The project shows the correct number of commits and only one contributor, which is me. However, the graph within that project shows that I haven't committed anything since February, even though my commits are all present up to current. (See graph screenshots at the bottom.)

Below is a screenshot showing my author name and email address in the last counted commit and the first non-counted commit. I have not changed computers and can't think of anything else that may have changed (please disregard the typo in the screenshot).

[image]

From this screenshot below, you can see that GitHub still considers all of my contributions as coming from my account, even the ones that aren't being counted.

[image]

I may have created new branches and pushed them up to the repository around that time but I can't say for sure or if it's related to this issue. Even still, the master branch for which I've always had has commits through the end of March.

I'm stumped.

These graph should show an equivalent amount of activity in April. The first is for the project that isn't being counted and the second is what shows on my profile.

This 870 should be 942.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which graph are you looking at (is it possible to show a screenshot)? The setting mentioned should only affect your profile – is it also wrong?

Comment: I just updated my question with the graphs, one on the project and one on my profile, neither of which is reporting my activity.

Comment: Does this have something to do with that I recently started committing to a dev branch instead of master, and then I merge dev into test and then into master as I plan my rollouts?

Comment: Yep, that’s exactly what it is. https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#commit-was-not-made-in-the-default-or-gh-pages-branch The default branch is configurable, so if it suits your workflow, you can change it to dev and get everything counted immediately.

Comment: The solution is to create a pull request but the branches are already merged with some of the commits. Hmm.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the others who have answered in the comments, I just wanted to provide the clear answer for anyone else that needs it.

GitHub doesn't count commits in your contributions graph in your profile unless the commits occur to the default branch. Rather than merging the branches into the default in git, create a pull request in GitHub and merge branches that way.